# Kafka consumer not able to connect to zookeeper - Session 0x0 for server null

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-zookeeper, apache-servicemix

I have been trying to run Kafka consumer inside servicemix.  The consumer is able to run correctly, when i run it using mvn camel:run. However, the connection to zookeeper fails inside servicemix with following error:

```
2014-11-05 13:57:08,125 | INFO  | l Console Thread | VerifiableProperties             | ?                                   ? | 217 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka_2.10 - 0.8.1.1 | Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 172.17.0.5:2181
2014-11-05 13:57:08,126 | INFO  | l Console Thread | ZookeeperConsumerConnector       | ?                                   ? | 217 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.kafka_2.10 - 0.8.1.1 | [group2_sumit-lm-1415224628125-d456f96e], Connecting to zookeeper instance at 172.17.0.5:2181
2014-11-05 13:57:08,126 | INFO  | l Console Thread | ZooKeeper                        | ?                                   ? | 250 - org.apache.hadoop.zookeeper - 3.4.6 | Initiating client connection, connectString=172.17.0.5:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@79130d54
2014-11-05 13:57:08,126 | INFO  | -172.17.0.5:2181 | ZkEventThread                    | ?                                   ? | 259 - wrap_mvn_com.github.sgroschupf_zkclient_0.1 - 0.0.0 | Starting ZkClient event thread.
2014-11-05 13:57:08,128 | WARN  | 172.17.0.5:2181) | ClientCnxn                       | ?                                   ? | 250 - org.apache.hadoop.zookeeper - 3.4.6 | Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ietf/jgss/GSSException
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:945)[250:org.apache.hadoop.zookeeper:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1003)[250:org.apache.hadoop.zookeeper:3.4.6]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException not found by org.apache.hadoop.zookeeper [250]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_65]
```

The zookeeper and kafka are running inside docker containers on my local machine only.  The connectivity is not issue here because i can telnet to zookeeper at port 2181.  I cannot seem to get anything from zookeeper logs as well.  Logs on zookeeper are in encrypted format.  Is there a way to debug this issue from either inside servicemix or from zookeeper?

Any pointers will be really helfull.

Answer (score 0):

I just have a quick search of [GSSException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/ietf/jgss/GSSException.html), it looks you need to change the servicemix etc/jre.properties file to export the "org.ietf.jgss" package from JVM.

Answer (score 0):

A bug was filed at [Zookeeper Site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1942)